# LinkedIn Social Wall | Is there a plug-in (Free / Paid) to display a LinkedIn feed in a social wall (not just a feed)?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, social-sharing, social-connect

I have been researching plug-ins that have the capabilities of displaying a LinkedIn feed in a beautiful social wall style, to no-avail.

Previously, I had one that was working however they disabled the ability to display LinkedIn feeds due to the changes in LinkedIn's policies.

I have yet again been tasked with creating a tiled LinkedIn feed (with permission to purchase a plug-in). I told him it is not possible but I am hopeful someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

Failing that, can anyone provide snippets of a scrapper tool they have created that would replicate the previously accepted social wall style plug-in?

A big thank you to all contributors, Jason.

Comment: Have you found something?

Comment: Unfortunately not! Sorry :c